# Can You Prove a Chat Happened Online?

Tags: authentication

With so much communication happening online nowadays the needs to verify information is obviously an essential.  However, let's say something was said in an online chat room/or private chat client, such as skype, and you need to share that information.  Is it possible to verify this information and present it to other people authentically?  Obviously screen shots and copy pastes of chats are not verifiable or reasonable for evidence.  Is there any way to implement a method of authenticating that a chat actually happened?

I'm thinking this is perhaps impossible with P2P clients like skype, as the server doesn't even have logs of the chat.  What then can you do?  Does anyone have any theories or ideas?

Comment: If it was a legal matter, Skype could be subpoena'd for logs

Comment: And the server DOES have logs with Skype. How do you think that when you login from a different device you get all your chats?

Comment: Is there anyway to authenticate these logs from the viewpoint of someone who isn't the server?

Comment: One option is to let who you're trying to prove authenticity to access your account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad because, while individual services and technologies may provide a means of non-repudiation, there is no general answer for all messaging services and technologies. A more specifically worded question may be more answerable.

Comment: Skype isn't P2P a and it hasn't been P2P for years.....

Answer (score -1):

One use of PGP is [to provide message authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Digital_signatures); so if the chat messages were signed, you would have good confidence that the person on the other end has access to the corresponding private key.  The other party could still claim their key was stolen, however.

Comment: I think what he's trying to ask is like.. If he was trying to prove someone said something to him, to his friend, but how would his friend know that he didn't just photoshop it? or some other technique to come up with fake information etc.

Comment: You can't prove that you actually sent a message with PGP being used the way you descibe, just that you created the text and signed or encrypted the message. I don't think this solution really helps.

Comment: It's unlikely the specific situation OP is asking for would involve public key signing, but if it did, that also provides integrity checking to ensure no one has tampered with the message.